# Not able to access http server running on mac from other devices in local network

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I have create a http server(on my mac machine) using node js which is listening on port 8081. I am not able to access this server from other device(e.g. my mobile) using my local IP address and port. Both my laptop and my mobile are in same local network(same subnet). 
How can I access my server on my mobile.

Following is my code snippet.

```js
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   
   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);
```

Comment: what is the response you are getting on mobile device? when you type ip:port in browser ?

Comment: It should work from any device on the same local network. If it doesn't, it's probably a firewall issue, your Mac blocking Node's outside communication.

Comment: on my mobile device i am getting `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`.

Comment: It worked. Needed to disable SIP Firewall of my home's wifi-router.

Answer (score 0):

to access localhost from another device you have to expose your port on the internet creating a http tunneling. Check this answer i gave some time ago: [Node.js app from localhost to the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859267/node-js-app-from-localhost-to-the-web/43859310#43859310)

Comment: Not on the same local network. Just launch your Node server, and access it from nearby devices using IP:port.

Comment: he is not using ngrok

Answer (score -2):

you need to find out on which IP address your Mac connected example 192.1168.43.23, then host your code on that ip like `http.createServer().listen(8081, 192.168.43.23);`

then open url in your mobile browser 192.168.43.23:8081,

this will do the trick

Comment: OP said he did just that, and it's not working. "I am not able to access this server from other device using my local IP address and port."